What is the reason behind the growing Secured Overnight Financing Volume?
I was looking at the NY FED's page (https://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/reference-rates/sofr) and saw the following chart:

Question: Is there a straightforward explanation as to what drives the increase in the borrowing volume? Shouldn't this volume actually go down as rates go up?
